# Absolute Positioning with jQuery UI dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, position

I'm using a few jQuery UI modal dialogs and the positioning of each dialog is set to relative by default. This is causing me a few problems and I'd like to know if there's some way I can get the positioning to be 'absolute' by default.

It seems to me that absolute positioning would make more sense in any case.. Is there any reason in particular for the use of relative positioning for dialogs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whoops, I just realised why this was happening - I wasn't using the jQuery UI css files (in which, I assume, the position of the dialog is set to absolute). Since the position wasn't set to absolute, by default jQuery UI used relative positioning.

I merely had to set the position of the dialog to absolute in my own css sheet:

```
.ui-dialog {
    position:absolute;
}
```

And my problem is solved.

Silly question, with an obvious answer that I should have tried before I asked it. I'll leave it up here in case someone else happens to run into the same issue though.

Comment: So, how can I force the dialog to open at location say (150, 150)? Alternatively, how can I remember the last position of the dialog and open it right there next time?

Comment: +1 wish I'd found this an hour ago. No idea why jQuery UI thinks it's a good idea to set relative positioning on a dialog when it doesn't have positioning explicitly set in the CSS.